# Retrieve and display image from PostgreSQL database using Servlet and JSP

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp, servlets

I want to upload an Image and then display it on JSP.

Here's my servlet

```
    public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // gets values of text fields
            String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
            String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
            InputStream inputStream = null; // input stream of the upload file
            Part filePart = request.getPart("photo");
            if (filePart != null) {
                inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
            }

            Connection conn = null; // connection to the database
            String message = null; // message will be sent back to client

            try {
                // connects to the database
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=test", "postgres",
                        "password");
                System.out.println(conn);

                String sql = "INSERT INTO personal_data (first_name, last_name, photo) values (?, ?, bytea(?))";
                PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                statement.setString(1, firstName);
                statement.setString(2, lastName);

                if (inputStream != null) {
                    // fetches input stream of the upload file for the blob column
                    statement.setBinaryStream(3, inputStream);
                }

                int row = statement.executeUpdate();
                if (row > 0) {
                    message = "File uploaded and saved into database";
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                message = "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage();
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (conn != null) {
                    // closes the database connection
                    try {
                        conn.close();
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                request.setAttribute("Message", message);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/Message.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
        }
    }
```

> My data gets stored successfully into the database, I need some reference or code for retrieval of `bytea` image and displaying it on `Message.jsp`

If you could help, please suggest some reference or provide some piece of code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant or not but generally storing a whole file in DB is not a good choice...instead store file in some location in server and store the location of the image file in DB.

Comment: @SachinSarawgi this is storing an image file and then displaying it. I am also saving it the same way you have mentioned it. Since i am stuck here. I am asking a question.